# javascript upload error

Tags: javascript, jquery, upload

Can someone guide me to what error is the following code having? Thanks a lot!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
    // pass the dom node (ex. $(selector)[0] for jQuery users)
    element: document.getElementById('file-uploader'),
    // path to server-side upload script
    action: '/static/upload/php.php',
    onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON){
        $('#form_upload').html();
        $('#form_upload').append('<input type="hidden" name="upload_file" value="'+fileName+'" />');
        $('#form_upload').append('<input type="hidden" name="upload_file_path" value="'+/IT1234/01/Week1+'" />');
        $('#form_upload').submit();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second last brace (`}`) requires a closing parenthesis (`)`) after it. You should also place a semi-colon (`;`) after that.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
    // pass the dom node (ex. $(selector)[0] for jQuery users)
    element: document.getElementById('file-uploader'),
    // path to server-side upload script
    action: '/static/upload/php.php',
    onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON){
        $('#form_upload').html();
        $('#form_upload').append('<input type="hidden" name="upload_file" value="'+fileName+'" />');
        $('#form_upload').append('<input type="hidden" name="upload_file_path" value="'+/IT1234/01/Week1+'" />');
        $('#form_upload').submit();
    });
});
```